# Django filesystem storage for large number of files

Tags: python, django, filesystems, storage

Scenario:
A Django app generates a lot of small files related to objects in different models.

I've done a lot of search for avoiding generation of large number of files in a single directory, when using the default Filestorage.

Is **django-fsfield** the only open source solution for this? Anything else you would recommend for fixing the large number of inodes in a dir?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider storing the content in a MongoDB collection.

Since the files are small, you can create MongoDB documents with a single [binary field](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/binary.html#bson.binary.Binary) containing the file contents. "Small" in this case meaning less than the MongoDB document size limit, currently 16MB.

If you need to store big files, Mongo supports that with [gridfs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/index.html#module-gridfs).

See also [When to use GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/When+to+use+GridFS).

Answer (score 1):

I am using [django-castor](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/django-castor).

> django-castor is a re-usable app for Django which provides a
>   **content-addressable storage backend**. The main class,
>   `djcastor.storage.CAStorage`, is a type of `FileSystemStorage` which saves files
>   under their SHA-1 digest.
>
> - No matter how many times the same file is uploaded, it will only ever be
>     stored once, thus eliminating redundancy.
> - Filenames are pseudorandom and made up only of hexadecimal characters, so
>     you don’t have to worry about filename collisions or sanitization.
> - `django-castor` shards files in the uploads directory based on their
>     digests; this prevents filesystem issues when too many files are in a single
>     directory.

Answer (score 0):

Also can use a custom storage manager that if a file is small save this in a database model with binary field and save small files of more of 16MB and don't need use other database.